# Вывод нового значения переменной из другого файла python

Tags: python

У меня есть два файла main.py и enemy_stat.py

Как вывести новое значение переменной `enhp` из файла enemy_stat после оператора `if` в файле main?

Код файла main:

```
from enemy_stat import *

print(enemy)
print(enhp)

room = 'room1'
if room == 'room1':
    enemy = 'slime'

print(enemy)
print(enhp)
```

Код файла enemy_stat:

```
enemy = "sex"
enhp = 0

if enemy == "slime":
    enhp = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как вывести новое значение переменной enhp из файла enemy_stat

Что для этого нужно?

1. Что бы в файле enemy_stat имелся опреатор печати, например - print()
2. Что бы этот оператор каким-то образом **выполнялся** в процессе выполнения всей программы.

Ни того, ни другого у Вас нет. Ну, первое условие выполнить не сложно - вставьте оператор печати и всё. А вот выполнить второе условие значительно сложнее,

Существует только два метода передачи управления из одного файла программы в другой:

1. Вызов функции из второго файла
2. Вызов метода класса из второго файла или присвоение переменной экземпляра объекта.

Есть ещё более хитрые способы с обработкой прерываний, но о них говорить не будем.

Первый способ довольно очевидный. В файле enemy_stat организуем функцию

```
def print_enhp():
    if enemy == "slime":
        enhp = 10
    print(enhp)
    return
```

А в первый файл вставляем вызов этой функции, заменив оператор *print(enhp)* на вызов этой функции:

```
print_enhp()
```

Про использование классов говорить не буду, т.к. это очень обширная тема.